# Fast approximate counting in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm querying my database (Postgres 8.4) with something like the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE indexed_varchar LIKE 'bar%';
```

The complexity of this is O(N) because Postgres has to count each row.  Postgres 9.2 has index-only scans, but upgrading isn't an option, unfortunately.

However, getting an exact count of rows seems like overkill, because I only need to know which of the following three cases is true:

- Query returns no rows.
- Query returns one row.
- Query returns two or more rows.

So I don't need to know that the query returns 10,421 rows, just that it returns more than two.

I know how to handle the first two cases:

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE indexed_varchar LIKE 'bar%');
```

Which will return true if one or more rows exists and false is none exist.

Any ideas on how to expand this to encompass all three cases in a efficient manner?

Comment: Thanks for providing the version, but there's not really any "8.x" . The difference between 8.1 and 8.4 is huge. See http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/ .

Comment: I didn't realize the second part of the version number indicated a major release.  Post updated.

Comment: Yeah ... I don't like the versioning scheme for that reason, but there's a lot of resistance to changing it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT * FROM table WHERE indexed_varchar LIKE 'bar%' LIMIT 2
) t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be simple. You can use `LIMIT` to do what what you want and return data (count) using a `CASE` statement.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN c = 2 THEN 'more than one' ELSE CAST(c AS TEXT) END 
FROM 
     (
      SELECT COUNT(*) AS c 
      FROM   (
              SELECT 1 AS c FROM table WHERE indexed_varchar LIKE 'bar%' LIMIT 2
             ) t
     ) v
```